# References for De Rham’s cohomology and De Rham’s theorem

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, de-rham-cohomology

I’m looking for a reference (preferably lecture notes or a book) that introduces De Rham’s cohomology and gives a proof of De Rham’s theorem. It would be nice if they included some applications too. I have some background in differential geometry and calculus on manifolds, and a bit of background in algebraic topology (simplicial homology mostly) and very basic category theory.

I’ve found the book ‘From calculus to cohomology: De Rham cohomology and characteristic classes’ by Ib Madsen and Jørgen Tornehave which seems quite helpful but it doesn’t include a discussion of De Rham’s theorem/singular (co)homology and its relation to De Rham’s cohomology.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but when in grad school I bought a copy of Bott & Tu, *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*. It is in the Springer GTM series. I only ever studied the early chapters, because I never delved deeper into differential geometry, but I recall enjoying learning De Rham stuff from that book. IIRC fellow grad students who did specialize in the DG recommended it to me. Please take recommendations of relative experts more seriously than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a treatment of De Rham cohomology and De Rham's theorem in chapters 17 and 18 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* respectively.

I took an undergraduate course on differential geometry not long ago where this book was the main reference. I believe the categorical prerequisites - if any - should be very light.

In any case, as Jyrki says you should probably wait for an expert's opinion.